# Element not moving

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to move this discord widget to the left corner but for some reason, I can't.
I'm pretty new to web developing and this is my first attempt for a responsive web site so sorry I make some dumb mistakes xd
I've tried messing around with the position type and display and all of that but didn't really find what's wrong.

CSS:

```
body{
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


/* contact */
.contact{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 80px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10 5 50 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/* tablet */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .profile{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 10%;
  }

  .about__me{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 10%;
  }

  .contact{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 40%;
  }

  .somw{
    position: relative;
    width: 125%;
  }

  .somw__content{
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    left: 5%;
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    /*profile picture
  ----------------------------------------------*/
  .profile{
    position: static;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    right: 100%;
  }

  .about__me{
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    left: 541px;
    bottom: 90px;
  }

  .contact{
    position: relative;
    width: 20.4%;
    height: 280px;
    right: 200px;
  }

  .somw{
    width: 10%;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Custom Profile Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- contact -->
    <div class="contact">
      <div class="contact__content">
        <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=675446555901165568&theme=dark" width="370" height="300" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .contact{
    position: relative;
    width: 20.4%;
    height: 280px;
    right: 200px;
}
```

This code is almost the last bit of css. This is setting the div containing the widget you be 20% wide and 200px from the right.

You are trying to overwrite it above but css renders in order with the last rule overwriting the previous.

You are also overwriting outside of a media query, the media query is written to change layout at certain screen sizes and is how it is “responsive” so your style needs to go into the last media query for desktop